# How to click the kendo dropdown in selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I'm a beginner in selenium webdriver and I'm unable to click one particular dropdown so that I can select the values from the dropdown. Here is my webdriver code:

```
driver.findElement(
  By.xpath("/html/body/div[16]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[1]"))
    .click();
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ddlSaleItem_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" style="width: 115%;" aria-activedescendant="3597e7c2-7206-4a69-b9ca-a99cd87699aa">
  <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-focused">
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-input"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
      <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <div id="ddlSaleItem" data-id="" style="width: 115%; display: none;" data-role="dropdownlist">
  </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on dropdown induce `WebDriverWait`() and `elementToBeClickable`() and following `Xpath`

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='select']"))).click();
```